# Unable To Logout of Facebook using Socialize SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk

I am using Socialize SDK in lieu of Sharekit to integrate mail, twitter and facebook in my app.

I only need to post some string on the user's profile which is working fine for facebook and twitter.

Following is the workflow:

1. User clicks on share , selects facebook/twitter.
2. If it is for the first time user is sharing, facebook/twitter login screen pops up
3. User Logs in and after authentication, share is successful.
4. If user shares for the second time, facebook/twitter login screen doesn't popsup for authentication and the share is successful.
5. If user wants to logout of facebook/twitter, he goes to the settings panel and clicks on twitter / facebook button to logout.

   [When it goes back to share after log gin out, user clicks on twitter , login screen   pops up but when user clicks on facebook, a shadow box appears for few seconds and disappears and user is logged in with the previous account. ]

   How would i resolve this issue ?

I have tried using

```
[SocializeThirdPartyFacebook removeLocalCredentials] and also 

[SZFacebookUtils unlink];
```

how should i go about it

I tried Clearing all the cache and cookies as well but still the same result

```
 NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies =   [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];

        for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {

            NSLog(@"In For");
            [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];

            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults removeObjectForKey:kSocializeFacebookAuthAppId];
            [defaults removeObjectForKey:kSocializeFacebookAuthLocalAppId];
            [defaults removeObjectForKey:kSocializeFacebookStringForAPI];
            [defaults removeObjectForKey:kSocializeConsumerKey];
            [defaults removeObjectForKey:kSocializeConsumerSecret];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

1.In the advance settings of the app on facebook, i enabled native/desktop app

2.Disabled SSO in basic settings

3.Added de-auth callback url in advance settings

4.Added the following piece of code:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0)
        {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Facebook and twitter SDK save access token in cookies.

So you have to clear all cache and cookies when you are trying to use logging mechanism in your code.

Comment: check the updated question, i already did what u have mentioned but still the same result

Comment: I have tried FBSession instance and call logout. [objSession logout]; This might help you.

Comment: from where u have called FBSession..in socialize.. and how ?

Comment: wherever you want to logout just make the instance and call logout .thats it . you need not to make the global object for that.

Comment: plz upvote my answer if you think i researched well and its worth...it would help me with my repo and hopefully one day i shall be inducted in the rankings league as well