# Unable to logout from Facebook using Facebook SDK 3.5 in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

I am currently using Facebook SDK 3.5 for facebook login in my native iOS app. I have referred sample  [iOS codes by facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636530/logout-facebook-sdk-3-08) and implemented my login in the same way. Everything works absolutely fine until the Logout process. I am able to logout from FB but **NOT** completely. When i tap on the login button again, FB is showing a webpage with my credentials again and asking me to login with the same. I'v heard people say that it is a problem with Safari, so i manually deleted all the safari cookies and tried to login again, but to no avail. Is there any alternative way in which i can do this?? I also referred SOF for solutions and implemented the answers listed below, but they are not working out either.

[Login Logout issue with facebook iOS sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110740/login-logout-issue-with-facebook-ios-sdk)

[Logout facebook sdk 3.08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636530/logout-facebook-sdk-3-08)

EDIT -Posting the settings tab screenshot of the Facebook app page

[image]

Comment: if you are using fb for just sharing, try sharekit. http://getsharekit.com/

Comment: im using FB to get user credentials like name, email, profile pic etc...

Comment: @AforAlpha were you able to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't used Facebook SDK but I have used third Party SDK Socialize and was facing the same issue with Facebook logout. I was unable to logout and even if I did, it was showing my credentials when I tried to log back in.

I followed following steps which is irrespective of the SDK you are using (Be it sharekit, socialize or native facebook sdk)

[Ref Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280436/unable-to-logout-of-facebook-using-socialize-sdk)

1.In the advance settings of the app on facebook, i enabled native/desktop app

2.Disable SSO/DeepLinking in basic settings --> native iOS app. Earlier there used to be different options but now only DeepLinking is provided.

3.Add de-auth callback url in advance settings. It could be anything [For e.g. http://google.com]

4.Add the following piece of code where the user clicks LogOut button:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
     NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
     NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
     if(domainRange.length > 0)
      {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for the answer. I've done this earlier but seem to have forgotten !

Comment: Glad to know that my answer was helpful to you.
Hope this helps @AforAlpha as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. i am new to FB integration. Can you please provide me some more information about the SSO and de-auth call back and also where am i supposed to add this code... I have updated the question with a screenshot of the Facebook app settings page. I am not able to find the SSO option in my settings page. Apart from that what should be the de-auth callback URL??

Comment: @AforAlpha I have made some changes in my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @AforAlpha Did u try the solution. Can u please provide with an update.

Comment: @AforAlpha were you able to get the solution

Comment: @AforAlpha What are you getting ? any logs will do good ? Have you enabled native iOS App in Facebook App Settings page ?

Comment: Yes... but no change in the behavior and we are done with that app @innocentDemon.. I'm sorry as i don't have access to that code anymore...

Comment: @AforAlpha so how did you cracked the logout stuff. You havent posted or accepted any answer.

Comment: @AforAlpha Also, if you find my answer WELL RESEARCHED and JUSTIFIED, kindly, upvote it. One user (Lalith B) already upvoted it because its a verified answer.

Comment: @AforAlpha Kindly, Upvote the Answer. it would be really helpful for me. :)